# Can we solve most blindness by cadaver donation?

Tags: medical-science, ophthalmology, india

[image]

> India's total population 118 Crores<sup>1</sup>.
> Daily Death - 62389
> Daily Birth - 86853
> If Daily Dead People Donate their Eyes, within 11 Days All Blinds will be able to see
> Then in India there will be NO Blinds.
> Don't Delete this message without
> Sending atleast to 1 person
>
> KINDNESS Costs GREATNESS
>
> Don't Just Read... Please SHARE

This was shared in Facebook. The picture asserts that there are theoretically enough donors to solve most blindness in India.

The numbers suggest a maximum of 28% rejects. Does a good organ donation system make a **decisive impact** agaisnt blindness, given that all dead people cant give useful transplants?

---

1. Note that a *[corere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore)* is equlivient to 10,000,000 so the total population cited is 1,180,000,000.

Comment: I suspect that just comparing numbers will not be sufficient for this. In short, just because someone is an organ donor doesn't mean that the organs can be used for a very long list of reasons. Furthermore, just because some organs can be used, doesn't mean that all can.

Comment: Hmmm...[corneal transplants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corneal_transplantation) are safe and easy, so [cataract patients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataract) can be treated with dead people's eyes, but that is hardly "all blind".

Comment: Why the statistic for `Daily Birth`? Shouldn't there instead be a statistic about how many blind people there are? - [Eye Donor FAQ](http://www.uihealthcare.com/topics/medicaldepartments/ophthalmology/eyedonor/index.html); [According to the __WHO__](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs282/en/index.html) `80% of all visual impairment can be avoided or cured`.

Comment: Please explain your figure for "28% rejects". It doesn't seem to follow from the numbers given.

Comment: The claim provided is that ALL blindness will be removed, but the question title is "most" blindness, which no-one is claiming, making it more difficult to answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of the question asks if *most blindness solved by cadaver donation?* The World Health Organization states that:

> According to the latest assessment, cataract is responsible for 51% of
>   world blindness [1]

So, cataracts are responsible for the majority of blindness.  Cataracts are readily treated by replacement of the lens of the eye with an artificial intra-ocular lens made of a type of plastic.

Cadaveric eyes are only used to provide donor corneas ( transparent front part of the eye) for grafting.  The lens of the cadaveric eye is not used.

Corneal blindness ( often monocular ) is the second most common cause of blindness, and figures about 1/4 that caused by cataracts [2]

> Diseases affecting the cornea are a major cause of blindness
>   worldwide, second only to cataract in overall importance. The
>   epidemiology of corneal blindness is complicated and encompasses a
>   wide variety of infectious and inflammatory eye diseases that cause
>   corneal scarring, which ultimately leads to functional blindness. In
>   addition, the prevalence of corneal disease varies from country to
>   country and even from one population to another. While cataract is
>   responsible for nearly 20 million of the 45 million blind people in
>   the world, the next major cause is trachoma which blinds 4.9 million
>   individuals, mainly as a result of corneal scarring and
>   vascularization. Ocular trauma and corneal ulceration are significant
>   causes of corneal blindness that are often underreported but may be
>   responsible for 1.5–2.0 million new cases of monocular blindness every
>   year.

However, the authors conclude that surgery is not cost-effective way of treatment, and most cases are actually preventable.  Note also that corneal transplant requires the use of eye banks, and other sophisticated medico-surgical infrastructure.

> The message is clear that medical and especially surgical intervention
>   is not cost-effective in eliminating corneal blindness in developing
>   countries. Prevention, in the case of almost every disease involved,
>   is more cost-effective and ultimately more successful in decreasing
>   the prevalence of blindness. Schwartz et al. estimated that 95.5% of
>   all blindness in the population they studied in the Central African
>   Republic was preventable or treatable

So, the answer to the question, is no.  The message being passed around Facebook doesn't understand the cause of common blindness and the treatment.

[1] http://www.who.int/blindness/causes/priority/en/index1.html

[2] Whitcher et al [Corneal blindness: a global perspective](http://www.scielosp.org/scielo.php?pid=S0042-96862001000300009&script=sci_arttext) http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/S0042-9686200100030000